# Xcode 10 Swift-ObjC Dictionary compatibility

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization, xcode10

Weird situation I've stumbled upon once upgrading to Xcode 10.

I have an Objective-C class which I initialize in Swift. The initializer accepts `NSDictionary` as a parameter. If I pass in the dictionary directly into the initializer like so:

```
let car = Car(parts: [myKey : myValue])
```

Then, back in ObjC world, when printing the contents of the dictionary it shows the value as `"(null)"`.

Everything works fine if I do:

```
let parts = [myKey : myValue]
let car = Car(parts: parts)
```

This issue exists on any version of Swift on Xcode 10. The issue doesn't exist on Xcode 9.

I am attaching a [sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eq10Noj6LrawpErBNXXKVe_cNeMFKV_k) where this is illustrated.

Comment: I also encountered this problem. Looks like a bug in the Xcode 10

Comment: @IlyaKharabet Have you filed a bug report for this ?

Comment: No I didn't, but I hope this will fixed in the future release

Comment: I've added an issue https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9036